# Define the upper abs only workouts-low body fat

Tags: workout-routines, abdominals, core

I want to define the upper abs, I am interested only in workout programs.

My food intake is ok but I do not think I am doing proper a workout; I don't have much bodyfat and I want to focus only on this specific area.

Where should I start?

I have seen internet a lot but I can't say I am impressed about those.

Could you tell me which workouts will help to show the upper abs?

Comment: There is no such thing as working only the upper or lower abs. It is all one muscle.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple causes of this, one can be your genetics although I highly doubt it despite being a possibility. The second is in all seriousness just because your other abs show does not mean your diet is good enough yet and believe it or not that could be the area in which your body is storing fat more even though it doesn't look like it. It is the same case with being skinny fat, where you are skinny and you only have a basic four pack because realistically there is still fat covering the general area. As of for exercises in general, upper circle crunches are a great exercise. Cable crunches, and doing over the head decline sit ups are also pretty reliable. The overhead decline sit up can also be preformed on the floor in a different fashion.